# Sequential Testing of Poisson Process

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-process, sequential-analysis

My question is related to the paper "Sequential Testing for Poisson Processes" by Peskir and Shiryaev, available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1015952000).

Specifically, suppose that there are two states of the world, G(ood) and B(ad), and the agent wants to take a correct action but doesn't know the state of the world. She does have some prior that the state is G, say, *p*.

Starting at t=0, she begins observing "news". In state G, news are modeled by a Poisson process with a known parameter $\lambda$. In state B, no news is ever observed (say, it's a Poisson process with parameter 0).

Perskir and Shiryav solve the problem for sequential testing between two Poisson processes with parameters $\lambda_1 > \lambda_0 > 0$. As far as I can tell, their method isn't directly applicable for when $\lambda_0 = 0$.

I have an intuition, which is somewhat confirmed by trying to solve the discrete-time case, that the agent's strategy would be characterized by a cutoff time for not observing any news. Obviously, once an arrival is observed, her belief would drift to 1, and the correct action for state G will be taken. If no signal is observed for long enough, she would take the action for state B. I am having trouble formalizing this solution and finding the value of that cutoff. Any help would be greatly appreciated!